# Proving big-O notation?

Tags: asymptotics

$2n^2 \in O(n^2-19n)$

This was proven in my lecture notes but it didn't make sense to me.

I tried solving for c like this:

$n_0 = 1$

$2n^2 ≤ c * n^2 - 19n$

$2 ≤ c * (1-19)$

$2 ≤ c * -18$

$-36 \leq c$, but $c$ has to be a positive constant.

Comment: you divided 19n by n, not n^2

Answer (score 3):

You have to show that there exists a
$c > 0$ and an $N$ such that,
for $n > N$ you have
$2n^2 < c(n^2-19n)$.

This is the same as
$2n < cn-19c$
or
$n(c-2) > 19c$.

This needs $c > 2$,
so lets choose
$c=3$ and see how large
$n$ needs to be.

For $ c=3$, this is
$n > 19\cdot 3 = 57$,
so $N=60$ certainly works.

Therefore, for
$n > 60$ and $c=3$ we have
$2n^2 < c(n^2-19n)$.

Note that we do not have to find the best $N$ and $c$ -
finding any that works is enough.

With enough practice,
you will be able to look at problems like this
and say "anything fixed times n is smaller than $n^2$
so we can ignore the 19n. 
Then anything fixed times $n^2$ is
$O(n^2)$ so that is true."

Answer (score 1):

Often it is easier to consider a quotient and study its behaviour as $n\to \infty$. Here you have

$$\frac{n^2-19n}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{19}{2n}\geq \frac{1}{4}
\quad \text{for} \quad \frac{19}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{4} \iff n \geq 38$$

So, you have for $n \geq N=38$: $\boxed{2n^2 \leq 4(n^2-19n)}$ which means exactly that $2n^2 \in O(n^2-19n)$.